# Jenkins fails to build Java project if local jar file included in pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, jenkins

This time we use `Jenkins` to help us to build Java, it used to work well, but if we add a local jar file, it failed.

```
...
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project ruoyi-admin: /BOOT-INF/lib/cesiumlanguagewriter-2.20.1.jar (No such file or directory) -> [Help 1]
[ERROR] 
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/qrd_back/ruoyi-system/pom.xml to com.ruoyi/ruoyi-system/3.8.5/ruoyi-system-3.8.5.pom
[JENKINS] Archiving /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/qrd_back/ruoyi-system/target/ruoyi-system-3.8.5.jar to com.ruoyi/ruoyi-system/3.8.5/ruoyi-system-3.8.5.jar
[ERROR] To see the full stack trace of the errors, re-run Maven with the -e switch.
[ERROR] Re-run Maven using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command
[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :ruoyi-admin
...
```

this jar file `cesiumlanguagewriter-2.20.1.jar` is our local jar file, we include it in `ruoyi-admin\pom.xml` file

```java
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <parent>
        <artifactId>ruoyi</artifactId>
        <groupId>com.ruoyi</groupId>
        <version>3.8.5</version>
    </parent>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>
    <artifactId>ruoyi-admin</artifactId>

    <dependencies>

        ......
        <dependency>
            <groupId>cesiumlanguagewriter</groupId>
            <artifactId>cesiumlanguagewriter</artifactId>
            <version>2.20.1</version>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <systemPath>${project.basedir}/lib/cesiumlanguagewriter-2.20.1.jar</systemPath>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>lib</directory>
                <targetPath>/BOOT-INF/lib/</targetPath>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.jar</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                ...
            </plugin>
            <plugin>   
                ...
           </plugin>   
        </plugins>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
    </build>

</project>
```

it looks fine, and exactly, it can build with command `mvn clean package` in our local **Windows environment**, and in our local **Ubuntu environment**, but not enable to build in Jenkins, what are the difference between the Ubuntu environment and Jenkins?

Ubuntu and Jenkins use the same `Maven`, the difference between them may be the `settings.xml`, but because I am newbie in Java, so I can not find the difference between them

the mavn version on the Ubuntu(it can build success):

```
jenkins@sakuramoyu:~/workspace/ruoyi_qrd$ mvn --version
Apache Maven 3.6.3
Maven home: /usr/share/maven
Java version: 11.0.19, vendor: Ubuntu, runtime: /usr/lib/jvm/java-11-openjdk-amd64
Default locale: en_US, platform encoding: UTF-8
OS name: "linux", version: "5.15.0-71-generic", arch: "amd64", family: "unix"
```

**Edit**

The command Jenkins use is `mvn -B -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/qrd_back/pom.xml clean package`, I think it will cause the problem, what are the difference between `mvn clean package`

**Edit2**

If I run build with `mvn -B -f /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/qrd_back/pom.xml clean package -X`, it tells me

```
...
[DEBUG] ignoreDelta true
[INFO] Copying 1 resource to /BOOT-INF/lib/
[DEBUG] file cesiumlanguagewriter-2.20.1.jar has a filtered file extension
[DEBUG] copy /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/qrd_back/ruoyi-admin/lib/cesiumlanguagewriter-2.20.1.jar to /BOOT-INF/lib/cesiumlanguagewriter-2.20.1.jar
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Reactor Summary for ruoyi 3.8.5:
[INFO]
[INFO] ruoyi .............................................. SUCCESS [  0.186 s]
[INFO] ruoyi-common ....................................... SUCCESS [  8.158 s]
[INFO] ruoyi-system ....................................... SUCCESS [  2.043 s]
[INFO] ruoyi-framework .................................... SUCCESS [  1.785 s]
[INFO] ruoyi-quartz ....................................... SUCCESS [  1.148 s]
[INFO] ruoyi-generator .................................... SUCCESS [  1.174 s]
[INFO] ruoyi-admin ........................................ FAILURE [  0.701 s]
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  15.679 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2023-05-23T09:40:23+08:00
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project ruoyi-admin: /BOOT-INF/lib/cesiumlanguagewriter-2.20.1.jar (No such file or directory)
-> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project ruoyi-admin: /BOOT-INF/lib/cesiumlangua
gewriter-2.20.1.jar (No such file or directory)
...
```

it means the local jar file is filtered? so it can not find it?

Comment: Do not use images for textual information like logs and configurations in Stackoverlow.

Comment: First using this: `org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) on project ruoyi-admin: /BOOT-INF/lib/cesiumlanguagewriter-2.20.1.jar`. on a spring boot project looks completely wrong... I don't know what you are trying to do here? Packaging of the jar in spring boot the spring-boot-maven-plugin is intended to handle that apart from that you use using an very old version of Maven. Furthermore using `-f ` option in Jenkins build looks a bit strange to be honest... why do you need that? The project can be built from root location...via configuration...

Comment: @khmarbaise first question, cause `cesiumlanguagewriter-2.20.1.jar` is a local jar we build, we can not find it on the public maven repo. The second quesition, the Jenkins use of `-f` was not defined by us, it's the default by Jenkins. I think your opinion is right, it may cause by the folder Jenkins choose to run maven was wrong, so it can't find the external jar file.

Comment: Start using a repository manager / Proxy and deploy your own artifacts there...

Answer (score 0):

You are not building that jar. You are telling Maven that it is to be found at a given directory relative to the project directory. It seems that in the Jenkins build that directory is set to a path where that jar is not there:

```
/BOOT-INF/lib/cesiumlangua
gewriter-2.20.1.jar (No such file or directory)
```

You didn't share enough information to find more but if you are using a Maven plugin to copy the jar file it maybe filtering a jar file because it is not supposed to do that.

Comment: that `cesiumlanguagewriter-2.20.1.jar` jar is built before maven start building, I try to install it in the maven local path

Comment: You should publish it to a Maven repository, the local one or a remote one. Don't treat a library as a resource.

Answer (score 0):

after a long time struggle, I found a solution: Edit `ruoyi-admin\pom.xml`,

remove all the resource part in `<build>`

```xml
<!-- REMOVE IT -->
<resources>
  <resource>
     <directory>lib</directory>
     <targetPath>/BOOT-INF/lib/</targetPath>
     <includes>
        <include>**/*.jar</include>
     </includes>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

add one line here:

```xml
<plugin>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>2.1.1.RELEASE</version>
  <configuration>
    <includeSystemScope>true</includeSystemScope> <!-- HERE -->
    <fork>true</fork> 
  </configuration>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <goals>
        <goal>repackage</goal>
      </goals>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

sorry I just a newbie in Java and Maven, so why it can happen, I don't know

**EDIT:**

it may cause by the folder run maven bu Jenkins, I think if I change `<targetPath>/BOOT-INF/lib/</targetPath>` to `<targetPath>BOOT-INF/lib/</targetPath>`, it will work.